# Audio editing on Linux

Tags: linux, audio-recording, sound-editing

I am helping to setup a Linux machine at my school for an audio editing room. We have a soundboard with audio incoming from multiple microphones, as well as outputting to 4 speakers. I am looking for any software that may be good for audio editing or capture.

Please note, the PC is not exactly amazing specs, so I cannot use high end software that requires more than 2 cores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

and it works on any platform!

Comment: I have used that before, so it would not be hard for me to get going.

Answer (score 0):

[Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/download.php)

Open source software designed for DJs. Might work for you.